# C# - крут или не крут?

Tags: c#, .net

Изучаю php по неволе. И понятно, наверное, почему думаю перейти на что-то более возвышенное. Тут внезапно взгляд упал на C#.  Давно читал где-то плохие отзывы о нем, и хоть читал давно а осадок остался, несмотря, что язык жив. Радует тем, что компилируется, радует тем, что вроде бы имеет кроссплатформенность(mono), радует тем, что не php.

И вроде бы плюсов море, но как он ведет себя в роли веб-разработки? Привычная модель LAMP, WAMP мне понятна, но как .NET  реализуется в винде, какая связка технологий используется я не в курсе. Не просвятите?

Comment: Вопрос крайне холиварен, задан в лоб что только прибавляет холиварности... 

Мое имхо если пишите именно под веб - лучше учите java, вот кто-то а она действительно кроссплатформена. 

PS: Не совсем понятно что значит изучаю php по неволе?О_о

Comment: На работе спросили разметку html знаешь - ответил нет. И вот теперь знаю php.

Comment: Холивара нет, т.к. я не сравниваю две технологии, а прошу дать оценочную характеристику C# и технологии .NET в целом. И заметьте я не просил давать альтернативы (это я про Java).

Comment: *а прошу дать оценочную характеристику C#* на это можно сказать только одно: ***Всяк кулик свое болото хвалит***. я скажу что **крут** придет *адепт* любого другого *языка программирования/фреймворка* и начнется ... **холивар**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый язык крут по своему и я считаю C# одним из лучших на сегодняшний день. Но не понятна ваша цель изучения языка. Вы говорите про кроссплатформенность, компилируемый и тд, но какова же цель?? Нет НИКАКИХ проблем в разработке на данном языке проектов "под веб" и связки обычно следующие: asp.net (C#) + mssql + IIS. Вместо асп-нет можно также использовать asp.net mvc и более того, вместо привычного всем флеша вы можете на том же C# писать "приблуды" для вашего сайта на SilverLight. Используя C# совместно с С++ вы сможете реализовать для виндоус практически что угодно!

Что касается рынка, то данный язык имеет ооочень не плохие позиции сегодня!

Comment: А IIS заменить в этой связке можно, винда в роли веб-сервера это как-то не очень.

Comment: можно, но это сулит проблемами... вы собираетесь прям так сразу написать адски нагруженное приложение и запустить его в жизнь? Очень много серверов живут по сей день на ИИС без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Alex-ом. Вопрос холиварный, но рискну предложить свой вариант. Попробуйте Ruby, вот он действительно кроссплатформенный. Правда он не компилируемый, но зачем вам компилируемый язык в вебных проектах. 
Что касается C# - я считаю, что это очень хороший язык (и даже, кое в чем, лучше java). Я его активно использую в настольных приложениях, но для вебных проектов, технологии Microsoft-а я бы использовать не стал.